# XCOPY command run OK first time. It fails 2nd time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I want to copy the config file from location "$(TargetDir)" to "%ProgramData%\A\B\" only once when application is built first time. Once this file is copied on the desired location there is no need to copy it again. I have written the following post build event in VS 2010. It runs first time successfully and copies the desired file at desired location but when application is built 2nd time it gives an error something like "the command ...... exited with error code 2". I googled but could not know the exact cause of the issue. From this script I am expecting that if desired directory already exists then XCOPY statement will not execute. PLease point me where I am wrong.

```
if exist "%ProgramData%\A\B\" == false
xcopy "$(TargetDir)C.exe.config" "%ProgramData%\A\B\" /F
```

Comment: Run the command with expanded paths on the command line, you'll see the full error.

Comment: I think you can't split if/xcopy that way, if you add a parenthesis then yes. Otherwise keep them on the same line. Test with "echo foobar", these will be output in the build window.

Comment: @PasiSavolainen: Tried paranthesis and tried to keep them on same line. No luck but error code changed to 9009.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know XCOPY will create the directory, if it doesn't already exist.

As you have already copied the files the first time, for the second Windows was trying to ask for overwrite confirmation on the XCOPY command. Visual Studio doesn't allow that, so it exited with Code 2.

You could try adding the /y param, which supresses the prompt, then it might work.

Comment: I don't want it to be copied again.

Comment: You could look to copy only if files are new or have changed /s /d. Post in superuser talks about the direct call via the command prompt. http://superuser.com/questions/308277/is-there-anyway-to-xcopy-just-changed-or-new-files

Comment: XCOPY new or changed file will not solve the issue as copied file will be modified by the program. Application wont modify source file. Hence source and destination will always different. As a result of command "XCOPY new or changed" will replace copied file withe the new one and all the modifications will be lost.